# read only primary emails in IMAP with s22 library

Tags: c#, email, imap, inbox

I am using `s22 IMAP` library to read emails from inbox it is work fine but it in read all email in inbox Primary, social and promotion emails how I can get only primary email.

```
using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient("imapHost", "imapPort", true))
{
    client.Login("Email", "Password", S22.Imap.AuthMethod.Auto);
    client.DefaultMailbox = "INBOX";
    IEnumerable<uint> uids = client.Search(SearchCondition.All());
    foreach (var uid in uids)
    {
        MailMessage message = client.GetMessage(uid, false);
    }
    client.Dispose();
}
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRdl8.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 'primary emails'? Are you talking about gmail - https://mailchimp.com/help/about-gmail-tabs/ ? Does https://superuser.com/questions/719677/how-to-use-gmail-tabs-with-imap help?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRdl8.png

Comment: it for gmail provider

Comment: Did you read and try the links I suggested? Do they solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if S22 will let you define custom commands or search parameters, or send raw commands, but if so, you can use [GMail's IMAP Extensions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions) to use their custom search language:

Here's a protocol level example of getting a list of recent UIDs in the primary category:

```
a UID SEARCH SINCE 1-May-2018 X-GM-RAW "Category:Primary"
* SEARCH 25032 25033 25034 25035 25036
a OK SEARCH completed (Success)
```

And here's the promotions tab:

```
a UID SEARCH SINCE 1-May-2018 X-GM-RAW "Category:Promotions"
* SEARCH 25026 25028 25030 25031
a OK SEARCH completed (Success)
```

Comment: (Note, it's unclear to me whether 'Primary' needs to be localized per language, like the folder names)

Comment: Also note: there does not appear to be any protocol way to get categories for a message, only messages for a category.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit), you can do this using MailKit's ImapFolder.Search() API:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
    client.Connect ("imap.gmail.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
    client.Authenticate ("username", "password");

    client.Inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

    foreach (var uid in client.Inbox.Search (SearchQuery.GMailRawSearch ("Category:Primary")) {
        var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage (uid);
    }

    foreach (var uid in client.Inbox.Search (SearchQuery.GMailRawSearch ("Category:Promotions")) {
        var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage (uid);
    }

    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```